# Detailed history of all commands/actions (also in GUI)

Tags: linux, command-history, desktop-environment

The famous `history` command shows us a list of recently executed commands. If we set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable we can also see *when* the commands where executed. I would like a more general version of this which also records some GUI-actions like opening/closing/etc programs.

Q: Is there a similar command to see "all" user actions (hopefully with a time-stamp)?
(of course not ALL. Not stuff like "moved mouse from here to there".)

But something along the lines:

```
18.06.2015 09:30 started Firefox
18.06.2015 09:32 started Rhythmbox
18.06.2015 09:35 opened someText.pdf in evince
18.06.2015 09:39 closed Firefox
18.06.2015 09:40 suspended session
```

would be super cool. Although other kinds of representations would be fine too. If it could even tell when some application gained focus this would be amazing.

Some ideas:
Maybe ...

- ... there is an extension for the desktop-env (using gnome here)
- ... some desktop-env supports this directly (I'd consider switching if this feature was available)
- ... there are some flags for the `ps` command to get some similar behaviour or at least get partially the information
- ... maybe it is possible to aggregate the information from commands like `history, w, ps` etc.

Note: I want this to monitor my own activity and I'm willing to write a small script for it. But for instance what would be suitable `ps`-flags and what should I possibly `grep` for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the activity journal to track opened files. Not sure if something exists to track opened apps though.

This is probably a dodgy and labour intensive solution, but you could use desktop icons to run the apps using scripts. In the script you could have it add a line to a log file.

Something like...

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date` "Firefox Started" >> /home/username/logs/apps-activity.log
firefox
echo `date` "Firefox Stopped" >> /home/username/logs/apps-activity.log
```

Sorry my bash skills are still fairly rudimentary, but I think you get the idea. Its not a nice solution, but perhaps it will give you some ideas. As far as using ps, each application can have quite a few processes involved, so would be fairly complex I think to get that working properly.

If we use the firefox example I get 2 processes running when I use the ps command. Eg.

```
$ ps aux | grep firefo[x]
username     5302 11.2  3.5 1391936 564016 ?      Sl   Jul08 553:26 /usr/bin/firefox.real
username    15351  0.8  0.2 482268 47040 ?        Sl   Jul09  29:21 /opt/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so -greomni /opt/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /opt/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /opt/firefox/browser 5302 true plugin
```